# What does F2 key do in normal mode

Tags: vim

When I press the `<F2>` key it hides the line-indicator in the bottom right (see pictures), is this regular functionality? If so, where can I find the docs for this? I have tried looking this up using `:help` and online as well I cannot find any of this.

Before pressing F2:

[image: Before pressing F2]

After pressing F2:

[image: After pressing F2]

Comment: `<F2>` does nothing out of the box in Vim.

Comment: Just found out I have binded `<F2>` to pastetoggle

Comment: You might want to post a quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some good digging through my vimrc files. I have found my `<F2>` is mapped to `'pastetoggle'`.